# How is calling a function on a subtype implemented?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, language-design, subtyping

I am currently designing a programming language and I'm curious on how to solve this problem:

Suppose that I have a class (or interface) A that looks like this:

```
class A { // size is 4 bytes
  int32 a = 0;
}
```

and a second class B that extends it and looks like this:

```
class B extends A { // size is 8 bytes
  int32 b = 0;
}
```

and that I have a function f that looks like this:

```
int32 f(A first, A second) {
  return first.a + second.a;
}
```

If I call it with two Bs, however, second.a would not be at the same location as if it were called with two As because the first parameter would shift it. My current thoughts for solving this are:

1. Disallowing unknown-size parameters, and forcing it to be passed as a pointer or reference (I think this is what Rust does)
2. Writing all of the following information to the call stack: pointer to second, pointer to after second, non-variable size params, first, second
3. Creating a function for each possible size of first and second and determining which one to call at compile time, if known, or at runtime using vtables.

The second idea would be a problem because it would need to be supported by all functions, even if they're rarely or never called using a subtype, which is inefficient.

The third idea would require a lot of functions to be created (a function that accepts 5 params which can be of 20 different subtypes would require 100 similar pieces of code to be generated, if it's called just one with unknown-type params), and would require a vtable for every class that has just one function using it. Also, a function in an already-compiled library could not be used with new subtype.

Combining 2 and 3 and creating two versions of the same functions, one that accepts only the type and another that accepts subtypes too could solve a few of these problems.

I'm curious about whether there are better solutions to this, and how other languages such as C++ implement this.

Comment: In C++, you'll *slice* the object, meaning the object that's copied to the stack as a parameter is essentially the first `sizeof(A)` bytes of the object provided as an argument. This is generally regarded as a danger of passing by value.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right SE site for this question, but off-hand I can't think where it should go. Possibly CS.SE.

Comment: @KyleStrand: What if the function calls a virtual function on the received param, and the overriding function uses the class's b value, which was sliced?

Comment: @Runemoro: once an object has been sliced, it's effectively of the target type - in facts to slice the very copy constructor of the target type is invoked. Copy semantics and virtual methods don't go together well in C++. If you want polymorphism to work correctly you pass by reference (which is exactly as almost any other language solves this problem).

Comment: To add on to MatteoItalia's comment, when the compiler generates code for a function, it generates *one* implementation, and it has *no way* of knowing anything about *how* the function will be invoked. So saying that a sliced object is "effectively of the target type" mostly means that you'll generate code under the *assumption* the bytes in question are in fact an object of the given type.

Comment: Do you want your language to be similar to C++ or Java? The answer to that will dictate how you implement handling of arguments to functions.

Comment: @RSahu, I want polymorphism to work similarly to Java, but with as little overhead as possible (not "everything is a reference", which is the way Java does it)

Comment: @Runemoro There's not much overhead to that -- a reference is just an implicit pointer. If you want runtime polymorphism, you pretty much have to have something analogous to C++'s vtable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because language design seems more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think you'll find that "everything is a reference" is the way *most* modern languages handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, calling `f(A)` with a parameter of subtype `B` by value is equivalent to

```
f(static_cast<const A&>(b));
```

The `static_cast` can result in the memory at the same address just reinterpreted as a start of a shorter block of data, or in transparently adding some offset first (if `A` is not the first base class or is virtual). After that, internally, a copy constructor of `A` is called. In either case, the information that was added by `B` is lost entirely, along with overrides of virtual functions. For all purposes, what is passed is no longer a `B`.

Dynamic polymorphism needs a reference or a pointer, much for the reasons you outline. But if you'd like to pass a "reference by value", the simplest solution would probably be passing a reference to a copy of the object. Note that in such case each object would need to "know" what type it is to call the correct copy constructor, or be derived from a common superclass and implement some form of `clone()`.